# Snap isn't working properly

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, snapping

I can't understand what's going on. I used snap to face with project individual elements, and I used proportional editing to stretch the vertices; but it doesn't work. Here are screen grabs showing my issue.
[image: look in edit mode]

[image: same side in object mode]

as you can see in object mode the view is awful and horrible. I managed to fix that in sculpting where I was able to stretch the icing but that's not what I saw in the tutorial. Can anyone explain to me what's the problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Snapping is working, but you don't have enough geometry for the icing to completely conform to the donut.  So when you snap one of the lower vertices to the face of the donut, the icing has to "dive into" the donut to reach the face.

I suspect you are able to "stretch" the icing in sculpting mode either because you don't have snapping on there or because you have one of the sculpting modes that is adding geometry.

You can accomplish the same thing in editing mode simply by turning snapping off temporarily and pulling the vertex away from the donut.

Answer (score 0):

The icing offset is -1 and it should be +1.This might be partly the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and procedure. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the workflow and how it works, feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be converted to a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)